# Incorrect behaviour of Intl.DateTimeFormat in headless Chromium during CI tests

Tags: angular, gitlab-ci, karma-jasmine

I'm encountering an issue with the Intl.DateTimeFormat in my Angular app when running tests in headless Chromium within my CI pipeline. The code works perfectly fine in browsers, but the output is incorrect when running tests in headless Chromium.

Here's a snippet of the code:

```
const options = {'calendar': 'persian', ...formatOptions};
// @ts-ignore
const formattedDate = new Intl.DateTimeFormat('fa-IR', options).format(date);
```

I expect formatting data have following output (And the output of the code in the real browser is this): "25 دی 1401", But, inside of the headless chormium, the formatted date is: "Dey 25, 1401 AP".
I've tried adding `--lang=fa-IR` inside flags part of my karma.conf.js file.
Also, I've added `LANG=fa_IR.UTF-8` and `LC_ALL=fa_IR.UTF-8` environment variables to my dockerfile. But, nothing changed.

When I used chromium version 99.0.4844.84 in my Gitlab pipeline, there was no such problem. But after updating to 102.0.5005.182, the `Intl` behavior changed to incorrect one.

Comment: Have you check the behavior on a more recent build ? (we're at 120 already)